# Laundry versus laundery

Tags: etymology

To wash clothes is to *laund**e**r*. Then why is there no *e* in laundry?

Is the base word same in both?

Was *e* used in laundry earlier? When did it come to be dropped?

Comment: There is no word *laundery* in the English language. You are confusing this with the verb *to launder*, which refers to both cleaning garments and "cleaning" money.

Comment: There is also *laundering* and *money laundering*, but not *money laundery*.

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanation. It really helped. I have edited my question now. Hope it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a historical dictionary like OED comes into its own, although since the entry for *laundry* was last updated in 1902, it lacks the detail of later editors:

> *Forms:*  Also 15 **landerie, landery,** 17 **landry.**
>   *Etymology:* Altered form of *lavendry n.* after *launder n.*

So the answer is broadly Yes. In the 1500s (I believe that 15 indicates the 1500s, not the 15th century) the word did appear with an *e* similar to *launder,* but it didn't have the *u* (or *v*) which its etymology indicates.

A launder (noun) at that time was "someone who washes linen" [OED], what we would now call a *launderer,* derived from the **verb** *launder.* *Launder* the noun is derived from an obsolete sense of *lavender,* someone who laves or washes. Since *v* and *u* were indistinguishable in many instances, it's easy to see how things developed.

Just for completeness, the **plant** lavender may have been so named because it was used in washing. OED has the following, again from 1902 (which may mean that "current" is no longer current):

> The current hypothesis is that medieval Latin *lavendula* is a corrupt form of *lavandula,* a diminutive of the shorter word which appears in Italian as *lavanda* (see **lavender** *n.* 1). This is commonly identified with Italian *lavanda* ‘washing’, the supposition being that the name refers to the use of the plant either for perfuming baths (so already in 16th cent. writers) or as laid among freshly washed linen. But on the ground of sense-development this does not seem plausible; a word literally meaning ‘washing’ would hardly without change of form come to denote a non-essential adjunct to washing. Besides, the earliest form appears to be *livendula;* if this could be connected with Latin *līvēre* to be livid or bluish, the sense would be appropriate, but the formation is obscure ...

Comment: Does this answer the question as to 'why the *e* is dropped (?)  when you compare today's  verb *launder* with today's  noun *laundry*'? I mean there's no surprise (to me) that there should be variant spellings centuries ago. Why is there no *e* in *laundry* today?

Comment: @Clare My reading of the OED's entries is that the *e* wasn't "dropped" so much as it only occasionally intruded into the word before the spelling was formalized. The word was originally *lavendry/lavendrie*, which entered the language in Middle English at least (pre-1500) and never had an *e* between the *d* and the *r*. It later evolved because of conflation with the word *launder* but anything like *laund**e**ry* would have been a nonce-spelling.